How to get a Cuda event time in CPU timeline?
Here's the pseudo code:
// the code before also calls kernels

for(int i{0}; i < n; ++i){
    auto& startEvent = startEvents[i];
    auto& stopEvent = stopEvents[i];

    cudaEventRecord(startEvent);
    kernel<<<1000, dim3{32, 32, 1}>>>();
    cudaEventRecord(stopEvent);
}

cudaDeviceSynchronize();

// get elapsed times

The code calculates the elapsed times for n kernel launches. The problem though is that it calculates relative times. I want to convert each start and stop events to a CPU timeline. In other words, I want to convert an event to a time since epoch (or to a time since program started).
Saving a current CPU time just before the loop will not help - because of a heavy GPU workload I don't know when the first kernel in the loop will actually start (assume there were a lot of other kernel calls before), and even if there were no work before, a kernel launch itself has an overhead.
One of the things to try is to add a callback cudaLaunchHostFunc. But as the documentation says, the function will block the following work in the stream. Since I have hundreds of kernels per frame, this callback could add a visible overhead to the program. I wish there would be something like cudaLaunchHostFuncAsync.
How do NSight tools get the precise timestamps for kernel start and stop?

you could launch a single event in a stream, with a callback to log the epoch time.  You could then do an elapsed time measurement from that event to every other event of interest, to get epoch time for those events.

Thank you, @Robert Crovella. I came to the same idea. Also, I'm thinking about nesting cudaEventRecord(event) exactly between two cudaDeviceSynchronize and recording an epoch time after the second sync. Assuming that these two timestamps (event and cpu epoch) happen at the same time it's trivial to convert each next event to cpu timeline. Though it's slightly simpler, I'm not sure that the second syncronization call will be fast so I can ignore it.

As was suggested by @RobertCrovella, one way to do this is to record event (gpuTimeline) and take a CPU time snapshot (cpuTimeline) at the same time. After that, the difference between another event and gpuTimeline can be added to the cpuTimeline to get a GPU time.
Here's how I'm doing this:
static uint64_t t1;
static uint64_t t2;

cudaLaunchHostFunc(0, [](void*){ t1 = getCurrentTime(); }, nullptr);
cudaEventRecord(gpuTimeline);
cudaLaunchHostFunc(0, [](void*){ t2 = getCurrentTime(); }, nullptr);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cpuTimeline = t1 + (t2 - t1) / 2;

Here I set callbacks immediately before and after the event recording. I'm assuming that the real time of event happens somewhere between these two callbacks. It works well for my needs.
